# PyTest mistakenly expects a library function which returns string as flask.wrappers.Response

Tags: flask, pytest, response, wrapper, python-3.8

My system setup:

```
Python 3.8.3
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
pytest version 5.4.2
```

I am using PyTest to test a library function which returns a string but pytest reports it as error as it expects `flask.wrappers.Response`. Code snippet:

```
from common.Authentication import Authentication

def test_tokengeneration_pass():
    """ JWT token generation should pass with valid user input parameter """
    token = Authentication.generate_token("test_user")
    assert type(token) is str
    assert token != ""
```

Error reported:

```
    def test_tokengeneration_pass():
         """ JWT token generation should pass with valid user input parameter """
         token = Authentication.generate_token("test_user")
>       assert type(token) is str
E       AssertionError: assert <class 'flask.wrappers.Response'> is str
E        +  where <class 'flask.wrappers.Response'> = type(<Response 36 bytes [400 BAD REQUEST]>)
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what `generate_token` actually does?

Comment: This is fixed. Environment variable was not set up for testing.